# How to replace any number of &nbsp; in string jquery

Tags: jquery, html, regex

I would like to replace a number of " " inside an html string to one space only. But, it will replace each and every single " " to a space, resulting in many spaces. For example,

```
htmlValue.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, " ");//"&nbsp;&nbsp;" becomes "  ". (2spaces) but I want only 1 space
```

Comment: can you please give us some sample string and expected output... that lets us to not guess anything

Comment: try `htmlValue.replace(/(&nbsp;)+/gi, " ");`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
/(&nbsp;)+/gm
```

and replace by single " "

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/DOre86/7)

Sample Code:

```js
const regex = /(&nbsp;)+/gm;
    const str = `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;sfdasdf&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`;
    const subst = ` `;
    const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
htmlValue.replace(new RegExp('&nbsp;', 'g'), ' ');
```